# How can I stress test a GPU?

Tags: gpu

I have a HP Pavilion dv5000 that is shutting down unexpectedly. I stress tested it with a BartPe CD ([UBCD4Win](http://www.ubcd4win.com/contents.htm)) using [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/) and it it ran at 100% CPU for hours without shutting down. This rules out the the CPU overheating from being the culprit.

I'm wondering if the GPU is overheating and how I would go about testing for that.

Ideas?

Comment: Let us know what the culprit was!

Comment: @Jim-McKeeth: It turned out to be spyware, which I'm busily removing now. Thanks for the solid leads on the GPU stress test. Another tool for the toolbox!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Furmark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) is a free GPU stress test utility that is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any modern 3D test.

Especially ATITool http://www.techpowerup.com/atitool/ Its work good for ATI and nVidia Cards. Can automatic test artifacts and overclock video card.

Also 3Dmark and etc...

Answer (score 0):

It's quite old now, but I like to test GPU performance with [rthdribl](http://www.daionet.gr.jp/~masa/rthdribl/) (Real-Time High Dynamic Range Image-Based Lighting).

Answer (score 0):

You also have [Video Memory stress Test](http://mikelab.kiev.ua/index_en.php?page=PROGRAMS/vmt_en) (which is included in [UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/))

Answer (score 0):

You can try Kombustor, it's light, provides all essential infos in an overlay in-test and it's highly adjustable.
Here is a version that I keep in my Dropbox :
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6015601/MSI_Kombustor_Setup_2.4.2.exe